# Py4j launch_gateway not connecting properly

Tags: java, python, gateway, py4j

I am trying to use py4j to open up a gateway that I can use to pass objects from java into python. When I try to open a gateway with the py4j function [`launch_gateway`](https://www.py4j.org/py4j_java_gateway.html#py4j.java_gateway.launch_gateway) it does not seem to properly connect to my Java class. However, when I launch my java class in the command line and then connect to it in python using [`JavaGateway`](https://www.py4j.org/py4j_java_gateway.html#py4j.java_gateway.JavaGateway) everything works as expected. I would like to be able to use the built in method as I am sure that I am not accounting for things that have already been considered in the design of py4j, but I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Let's say I wanted to create a gateway to the class `sandbox.demo.solver.UtilityReporterEntryPoint.class`. In the command line I can do this by executing the following:

```
java -cp /Users/grr/anaconda/share/py4j/py4j0.10.4.jar: sandbox.demo.solver.UtilityReporterEntryPoint py4j.GatewayServer
```

This launches as expected and I can use the methods in my class from within python after connecting to the gateway. So far so good.

My understanding of the py4j documentation would lead me to believe I should do the following to launch the gateway in python:

```
port = launch_gateway(classpath='sandbox.demo.solver.UtilityReporterEntryPoint')
params = GatewayParameters(port=port)
gateway= JavaGateway(gateway_parameters=params)
```

I get no errors when executing these three lines, but when I try to access my java class methods with `gateway.entry_point.someMethod()` it fails with the following error:

> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling t.getReport. Trace:
>   py4j.Py4JException: Target Object ID does not exist for this gateway :t
>       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:277)
>       at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>       at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>       at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Obviously something is not getting called correctly within `launch_gateway` or I am feeding it the wrong information.

In the py4j source code for [`launch_gateway`](https://github.com/bartdag/py4j/blob/master/py4j-python/src/py4j/java_gateway.py#L214-L332) you can see that given the inputs you provide and those constructed by the function, a command is constructed that eventually gets called by [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). So given the input passed to `launch_gateway` above the command passed into `Popen` would be:

```
command = ['java', '-classpath', '/Users/grr/anaconda/share/py4j/py4j0.10.4.jar:sandbox.demo.solver.UtilityReporterEntryPoint', 'py4j.GatewayServer', '0']
```

Passing this command to `Popen` returns the listening port as expected. However, connecting to this listening port still does not allow access to my class methods.

Finally, passing the command as a single string to Popen without the final argument ('0'), properly launches a gateway which again operates as expected. Having taken a glance at the Java source code for py4j.GatewayServer.class this makes no sense as the main method seems to indicate that the class should exit with status 1 if the length of arguments is 0.

At this point I'm kind of at a loss. I can hack my way into a workable solution, but as I said I'm sure that ignores important aspects of the gateway behavior and I don't like hacky solutions. I'd love to tag @Barthelemy in this one, but hopefully he reads this. Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

For now I have been able to work around this issue with the following steps.

1. Package entire project including all external dependencies into a single jar file `magABM-all.jar`, with 'Main-Class' set to `UtilityReporterEntryPoint`.
2. Include `if...else` block regarding presence of `--die-on-exit` exactly like it is in [`GatewayServer.java`](https://github.com/bartdag/py4j/blob/master/py4j-java/src/main/java/py4j/GatewayServer.java#L768-L800)
3. Use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to call the command to run the project jar.

UtilityReporterEntryPoint.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(new UtilityReporterEntryPoint());
  System.out.println("Gateway Server Started");
  server.start();
  if (args[0].equals("--die-on-exit")) {
    try {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        stdin.readLine();
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

app.py

```
def setup_gateway()
    """Launch a py4j gateway using UtilityReporterEntryPoint."""
    process = subprocess.Popen('java -jar magABM-all.jar --die-on-exit', shell=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    gateway = JavaGateway()
    return gateway
```

In this way I can still use `gateway.shutdown` if necessary and if the python process that starts the py4j gateway dies or is closed the gateway will be closed.

**N.B** I would by no means consider this a final solution as py4j was written by much smarter individuals with a clear purpose in mind and I am sure that there is a way to manage this exact workflow within the confines of py4j. This is just a stopgap solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. The classpath parameter in `launch_gateway` should be a directory or a jar file, not a class name. For example, if you want to include additional Java libraries, you would add them to the classpath parameter.
2. The error you receive when you call `gateway.entry_point.someMethod()` means that you have no entry point. When you call `launch_gateway`, the JVM is started with GatewayServer.main, which launches a GatewayServer with no entry point: `GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(null, port)`. It is not possible currently to use `launch_gateway` and specify an entry point.
3. When you start the JVM with `java -cp /Users/grr/anaconda/share/py4j/py4j0.10.4.jar: sandbox.demo.solver.UtilityReporterEntryPoint py4j.GatewayServer` I believe the JVM uses UtilityReporterEntryPoint as the main class. Although you did not provide the code, I assume that this class has a main method and that it launches a GatewayServer with an instance of UtilityReporterEntryPoint as the entry point. Note that there is a whitespace between the colon and the class name so UtilityReporterEntryPoint is seen as the main class and not as being part of the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess I am a little confused by point 2. Are you saying that with `launch_gateway` there is no way for me to launch my class `UtilityReporterEntryPoint`? If so is there a way for me to set the entry point after launching?

Comment: I'd still like to learn more about how to properly use the `launch_gateway` method, but for now I came up with a bit of a workaround. Take a look at my updated question and let me know if this makes sense. Like I said I really want to know how to do this the RIGHT way and not just some hacky fix.

Comment: @Grr there is no way to specify a main class with launch_gateway therefore, it is not possible to specify an entry point. The goal of launch_gateway is to get started as fast as possible. As soon as you need more configuration options, it is best to roll your own strategy such as the app.setup_gateway function you created. You may also consider opening a feature request to support custom Main class, but as you saw with --die-on-exit, the Main class would still have to follow some protocol.